# Rails - Simple_fields_for not submitting multiple records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form-for

I'm trying to create a form that allows a user to select different choices for each category on the same form, and each of these will create its own model. My problem is getting the form to submit multiple parameters. My code is as follows:

```
      <%= simple_form_for choices_path do |f| %>
        <td><%= person.fullname %></td> 
        <td><%= person.email %></td> 
        <td><%= person.phone %></td> 
        <% if Category.any? %>
          <%= f.simple_fields_for :choices do |g| %>
            <% Category.all.each do |category| %>
              <td>
                <%= g.input :item_id, as: :select, collection: booking.venue.menu_items(category) %>
                <%= g.hidden_field :admin_id, value: person.id %>
              </td>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
        <td><%= person.completed? %></td>
        <td><%= f.submit %></td>
      <% end %>
```

The idea obviously being to create a new form for each category. This works until submitting the data, where only the last form's data is submitted. My paramaters are as follows:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"tf3DSLGHyOVEVJkcLjSVE9HDJbjn1CIaYBJIfHFw6RYH8tcn0tNilWVIjzyvcjXYm2ovKNO5A31+TktGA8X2+Q==",
 "/choices"=>{"choices"=>{"item_id"=>"Dessert 1", "admin_id"=>"3"}},
 "commit"=>"Save /choices",
 "venue_id"=>"1",
 "booking_id"=>"26"}
```

I can see that its creating a hash and is ready to submit multiple choices, however it is only the last record's data that is submitted.

Any help on how to get multiple records to update is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The simple form association helper might be what you are looking for: 
[link](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#associations)